# Merge google-cloud-messaging into android-gcm

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The tags [google-cloud-messaging](/questions/tagged/google-cloud-messaging) and [android-gcm](/questions/tagged/android-gcm) are about exactly the same thing: the Google Cloud Messaging service for Android. Those tags should be merged and synonymized, [android-gcm](/questions/tagged/android-gcm) has more posts so that should probably be the main tag.

The predecessor to GCM uses the tag [android-c2dm](/questions/tagged/android-c2dm), keeping the tags in the same style seems reasonable.

Comment: I'm conflicted.  On the one hand, I don't like abbreviations like `gcm`.  On the other, `android-google-cloud-messaging` can be a mouthful.  Not sure which way I'd want to go with this.

Comment: I'm not comfortable with the abbreviation either, but Google's own documentation uses it, and the docs are the #2 result on Google itself for just "gcm".  The documentation also insists that it's an Android-specific product, so the Android prefix makes a tremendous amount of sense here.

Comment: I don't really care about the direction of the merge, might as well take the other one.