# Synonyms requests of android-gcm

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

EDIT: The [apple-push-notifications](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications) synonym was recently created (thanks!). Hopefully, we can get the [android-gcm](/questions/tagged/android-gcm) synonyms too.

Can we please make [google-cloud-messaging](/questions/tagged/google-cloud-messaging) and [gcm](/questions/tagged/gcm) synonyms of [android-gcm](/questions/tagged/android-gcm)?

It is clear that all three tags mean exactly the same thing (except for a few questions - 8 - about Google Cloud Messaging for Chrome, which is a totally different topic, and for which I created a new tag [chrome-gcm](/questions/tagged/chrome-gcm)), but users keep using all three of them in new questions, sometimes even in the same question.

As of 2014/01/14 :

- [android-gcm](/questions/tagged/android-gcm) 1146 questions (of which 1062 without [google-cloud-messaging](/questions/tagged/google-cloud-messaging) and 932 without [gcm](/questions/tagged/gcm))
- [gcm](/questions/tagged/gcm) 673 questions (of which 459 without [android-gcm](/questions/tagged/android-gcm))
- [google-cloud-messaging](/questions/tagged/google-cloud-messaging) 264 questions (of which 180 without [android-gcm](/questions/tagged/android-gcm))

It is clear that [android-gcm](/questions/tagged/android-gcm) should be the main tag. Only about 600 questions are missing this tag.

EDIT : the following part in no longer relevant (I wasn't sure whether to remove it from the question).

Can we also make [apns](/questions/tagged/apns) synonym for [apple-push-notifications](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications)?

It is clear both of them mean the same thing.

- [apple-push-notifications](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications) 1153 questions
- [apns](/questions/tagged/apns) 949 questions

Those are too many questions to re-tag, so a synonym would be better. I think [apple-push-notifications](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications) should be the main tag.

These synonyms were already suggested (some by myself and some by others) but it's hard to get people to vote for synonyms of less popular tags :

- [android-gcm synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-gcm/synonyms)
- [apple-push-notifications synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apple-push-notifications/synonyms)

(note that [apn](/questions/tagged/apn) is not related to Apple Push Notifications and was suggested as a synonym by mistake).

There were already some questions about these tags, but nothing was done to fix this issue :

- [We don't need three tags for Apple Push Notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120562/we-dont-need-three-tags-for-apple-push-notifications)
- [Merge google-cloud-messaging into android-gcm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145045/merge-google-cloud-messaging-into-android-gcm)

I ask whoever has the power to either create those synonyms or vote for the suggested synonyms.