# Synonimize [.net-micro-framework] and [netmf] tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I have noticed that there exist both [.net-micro-framework](/questions/tagged/.net-micro-framework) and [netmf](/questions/tagged/netmf) tags which refer to the same *.NET Micro Framework* technology.

I suggest to make [netmf](/questions/tagged/netmf) synonym of [.net-micro-framework](/questions/tagged/.net-micro-framework). That would help to have all questions related to it under same tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took me a moment to figure out there was actually a `.` in the tag name, but synonym created.

Comment: Hi animuson. I was wondering what are the criteria that moderators use when deciding to fulfill a synonym request.  I'm asking because a recent synonym request of mine was completely ignored.

Comment: @Eran: Generally if there's a clear sign that they definitely should be synonyms, we act on them when we see them. If we're not really sure when looking at them, we leave it alone so the community can discuss whether it's a legitimate synonym choice or not, and well, when you leave something sit for a while you tend to forget about it... Especially with the load of moderator flags we deal with.

Comment: Well, thanks for the explanation. In the case of my [synonym request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184502/synonyms-requests-of-android-gcm-and-apple-push-notifications) there were prior questions discussing the synonyms (links included in my question), and I felt there was a consensus regarding the desired course of action, but nothing was done about it. That's why I posted that question.