# Burninate [wp8] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[wp8](/questions/tagged/wp8) was recently created (oldest question from Jul 27) and has just 18 questions.

I don't think there is any difference between this tag and the more established [windows-phone-8](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-8) tag, which has 4684 questions.

So, should [wp8](/questions/tagged/wp8) be burninated?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In cases where two tags refer to the exact same thing, we don't just kill off one of them; we make them synonyms instead, which I've done now.

Comment: Really? I was under the impression that synonyms are created only when both tags have many questions, which would make getting rid of the less used tag harder. But a synonym works too. Thanks!

Comment: @Eran: You could remove the less-used tag yourself, but that doesn't stop it from being created again in the future. Since [wp8] is basically an abbreviation for [windows-phone-8], we may as well create a synonym right off the bat.

Comment: OK, BoltClock. Thanks! You know what's funny? When I [asked for tag synonyms a while back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184502/synonyms-requests-of-android-gcm-and-apple-push-notifications), my request was ignored, and now when I requested something else I got a synonym :)

Comment: @Eran: Heh... it's probably because there are so many questions with each tag, which as you say makes getting rid of the lesser tags harder. Synonyms are reversible without doing much damage in general, but I can see why none of us had looked into it yet - or we missed it.

Comment: @Eran One big difference is that *this* question is focused on two specific tags. It makes it much easier to understand and agree upon, and then much easier to take action on. The other question is like 2-3 questions in one.